# Crawl all the links of a page that is password protected

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am crawling a page that requires username and password for authentication. And I successfully got the 200 OK response back from the server for that page when I passed my username and password in the code. But it gets stop as soon as it gives the 200 OK response back. **It doesn't move forward in to that page after authentication to crawl all those links that are there in that page.** `And this crawler is taken from http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/`.
This is the code where I am doing the authentication stuff...

```
public class MyCrawler extends WebCrawler {

    Pattern filters = Pattern.compile(".*(\\.(css|js|bmp|gif|jpe?g"
            + "|png|tiff?|mid|mp2|mp3|mp4" + "|wav|avi|mov|mpeg|ram|m4v|pdf"
            + "|rm|smil|wmv|swf|wma|zip|rar|gz))$");

    List<String> exclusions;


    public MyCrawler() {

        exclusions = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Add here all your exclusions

    exclusions.add("http://www.dot.ca.gov/dist11/d11tmc/sdmap/cameras/cameras.html");

    }


    public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {

    String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();


    DefaultHttpClient client = null;

        try
        {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("WEB URL:- " +url);


            client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test", "test"));
            client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);



        for(String exclusion : exclusions){
            if(href.startsWith(exclusion)){
                return false;
            }
        }   

        if (href.startsWith("http://") || href.startsWith("https://")) {
            return true;
        }

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toString());

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("executing request" + request.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());



    }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return false;
    }

    public void visit(Page page) {
    System.out.println("hello");
    int docid = page.getWebURL().getDocid();
        String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
        System.out.println("Page:- " +url);
        String text = page.getText();
        List<WebURL> links = page.getURLs();
    int parentDocid = page.getWebURL().getParentDocid();


    System.out.println("Docid: " + docid);
        System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        System.out.println("Text length: " + text.length());
        System.out.println("Number of links: " + links.size());
        System.out.println("Docid of parent page: " + parentDocid);

}
}
```

And this is my Controller class

```
public class Controller {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            CrawlController controller = new CrawlController("/data/crawl/root");


//And I want to crawl all those links that are there in this password protected page             
            controller.addSeed("http://search.somehost.com/");

            controller.start(MyCrawler.class, 20);  
            controller.setPolitenessDelay(200);
            controller.setMaximumCrawlDepth(2);
    }
}
```

Anything wrong I am doing....

Comment: Where are you calling visit from?  Doesn't a web crawler need to recursively visit unvisited sites that are eligable (e.g not excluded, etc)?

Comment: @Amir Afghani, thanks for replying back..  I am using this crawler in my code..  `http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/` and this is the souce code I am using.. There are several classes inbuilt into this crawler.. `https://crawler4j.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/crawler4j/src/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/example/simple/`. This is the SVN location...

Comment: In your code you pasted, where do you call the visit method?

Comment: @Amir Afghani, I call that method from this location.  `https://crawler4j.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/crawler4j/src/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/WebCrawler.java`.

Comment: Are you sure?  WebCrawler.java is what you're extending, not the call site of visit.

Comment: Yes, I haven't modifed their code.. I am using the same crawler4j into my code.. Just that I want to crawl all the url's that are behind the password protected page. So I wrote authentication code in MyCrawler.java and that code works fine for authentication.. But it doesn't crawl the url of that link..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/ the shoudVisit() function should only return true or false. But in your code, this function is also fetching the content of the page which is wrong. The current version of crawler4j (3.0) doesn't support crawling of password-protected pages.

Comment: What is a best java tool/lib for that?

Comment: @AKIWEB Resurrecting an old post, But what can be java tool/lib for crawling webpages behind authentication (google authentication, I have to crawl an sites.google.com which requires authentication)